# Galera Manager on none Amazon environment

Tags: mariadb, galera

I want to create a MariaDB 10.4 multi-master cluster on four Ubuntu 20.04 nodes. As you know Galera manager provides a web GUI interface for the cluster and it's handy for monitoring and add or remove nodes.

But because I am not using Galera Manager on the Amazon ec2 platform, I encountered some errors, and here is what I've done:

1. I have ubuntu 20.04 with MariaDB 10.4 as node1.
2. On the node1 server, I have enabled root to log in over ssh.
3. On Galera manager which is on another Ubuntu server, I have imported root ssh keys to node1, so Galera Manager can access node1 server over ssh with root users.
4. On the Galera manager console I have created a cluster as you can see here:

[image: create cluster]

5. Then I added node1 server to the cluster as you can see here:

[image: add a node to cluster]

6. You can see the complete deployment log as you can see here:

[Full Log](https://cloudvyzor.com/logpad/?query&database=sandbox-d77e5f1f60e94a12e364812315f23f27)

7. After node installation finishes node status will become unknown as you can see here:

[image: Unknown node]

At this point, you cannot start or stop the node, and as you can see log files are empty! and the whole cluster becomes useless, no matter how many nodes you add they all become unknown.

I know that I can create a multi-master Galera cluster without the Galera manager, but as I mentioned before, I need it for monitoring and scaling

Comment: You might get more traction on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is very interesting and can be the first alternative to serveralnines clustercontrol, but as far i know, galera manager only works on aws, do you achieve make work on your cluster?

Answer (score 0):

In point 6, the complete deployment logs are missing -- can you reupload that?

At point 7, have you thought about clicking to start the node? Logs are empty, but the starting happens at the top right hand column, in the pull down, where you see UNKNOWN and the dots ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have edited the full log link but just to make sure that you can access it, I'm gonna paste it right here -> https://tinyurl.com/fullllllog. So here's the link as well. At point 7: yes I start the node but it won't turn on and in the job history tab, the node start task will become unsuccessful.

Comment: Hi @FardinKamali -- the file is now gone.